# How to change local/global or return variable from volley method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Is it possible to change the value of global variable or to return value from volley method. Im trying to return value but im not getting any value from this method. I need to return 'listaFilmovaSerija' ArrayList.

```
public static ArrayList<MoviesShowsModel> readJSON(Context context, String url, final ArrayList<MoviesShowsModel> listaFilmovaSerija, final boolean odredjenaVelicina){
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            listaFilmovaSerija.clear();
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String naslov = "";
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("results");
                            int d = (odredjenaVelicina)? 10 : arr.length();
                            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
                                JSONObject obj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                naslov = (getTabActive() == 0)? obj2.getString("title") : obj2.getString("name");
                                listaFilmovaSerija.add(new MoviesShowsModel(naslov,
                                        obj2.getString("poster_path"),
                                        obj2.getString("overview"),
                                        obj2.getString("backdrop_path"),
                                        obj2.getInt("id")));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("ISPIS","Desila se greska " + error);
            }
        });
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

return listaFilmovaSerija;}
```

Comment: just pass key to your method and check if your json contains that data return it. or use interface

Answer (score -1):

To get the response in ArrayList you have to implement Custom request of type ArrayList then only you will be able to get the desired response.

[You can read about it in official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom)

[and you can find tutorial here](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-a-custom-request-using-volley-library)

Example from Official documentation which is Custom GsonRequest

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Listener<T> listener;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */
    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
            Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linking to an external resources has the risk that if the link becomes stale, then your answer becomes useless.  Please consider to add some code here explaining what needs to be done.